# Unable to receive server name in SQL Server ADO.NET Entity Model Wizard

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to make a database model in my ASP.NET application but when try to select my Database server, the name simply doesn't load. It returns blank. Please check the image below. I have created an empty application and selected WebApi checkbox.
[image]

Comment: Network discovery of database servers is generally not particularly reliable. If you know the name of the server, simply enter it. If it's your *local* server, just use `.` (or `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`, if using LocalDB).

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert I tried both but didn't work. I had created SQL Server database.

Comment: @minsuga Try database authentication instead of Windows Authentication to sign into the server.

Comment: @ starbyone but I have Windows Authentication configured already while I had setup SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

use . (full-stop) to server name, and click test connection button it should work. If not, please check your  sql server run properly.